# Matlab - Dilation function alternative

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm looking through various online sources trying to learn some new stuff with matlab.

I can across a dilation function, shown below:

```
function rtn = dilation(in)

h =size(in,1);
l =size(in,2);
rtn = zeros(h,l,3);

rtn(:,:,1)=[in(2:h,:); in(h,:)];
rtn(:,:,2)=in;
rtn(:,:,3)=[in(1,:); in(1:h-1,:)];
rtn_two = max(rtn,[],3);

rtn(:,:,1)=[rtn_two(:,2:l), rtn_two(:,l)];
rtn(:,:,2)=rtn_two;
rtn(:,:,3)=[rtn_two(:,1), rtn_two(:,1:l-1)];
rtn = max(rtn,[],3);
```

The parameter it takes is: `max(img,[],3) %where img is an image`

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on what this function appears to do and if there's a better (or less confusing way) to do it? Apart from a small [wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation), I can't seem to find any documentation, hence asking for your help.

Could this be achieved with the `imdilate` function maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this is doing is creating two copies of the image shifted by one pixel up/down (with the last/first row duplicated to preserve size), then taking the max value of the 3 images at each point to create a vertically dilated image. Since the shifted copies and the original are layered in a 3-d matrix, `max(img,[],3)` 'flattens' the 3 layers along the 3rd dimension. It then repeats this column-wise for the horizontal part of the dilation.

```
For a trivial image:
00100
20000
00030

Step 1:
(:,:,1) (:,:,2) (:,:,3)     max
 20000   00100   00100     20100
 00030   20000   00100     20130
 00030   00030   20000     20030

Step 2:
(:,:,1) (:,:,2) (:,:,3)     max
 01000   20100   22010     22110
 01300   20130   22013     22333
 00300   20030   22003     22333
```

You're absolutely correct this would be simpler with the Image Processing Toolbox:

```
rtn = imdilate(in, ones(3));
```

With the original code, dilating by more than one pixel would require multiple iterations, and because it operates one dimension at a time it's limited to square (or possibly rectangular, with a bit of modification) structuring elements.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for the explanation. I really appreciate it. Can the 3D matrix returned from the imdilate function be flattened?

Comment: @Reanimation `imdilate` with a 2D image should return a 2D result - are you giving it an RGB image or something like that?

Comment: If I load the moon image (`img=double(imread('moon.tif'));`) and check it's size, it returns `(x,y)`, but If I load my image (`img2=double(imread('image_raw.jpg'));`) it's size is `(x,y,3)`... On my test image the imdilate is returning a 3d still I think... In another function I'm trying to add the imdilate to a 2d matrix which is why it's not happy. I'm thinking if I could flatten the returned 3d imdilate to a 2D, it will work?

Comment: @Reanimation Yeah, your image is getting loaded as RGB - best to use `rgb2gray` before you start, but there's not much harm in converting it later other than performance.

Answer (score 2):

Your function replaces each element with the maximum value among the corresponding 3*3 kernel. By creating a 3D matrix, the function align each element with two of its shift, thus equivalently achieves the 3*3 kernel. Such alignment was done twice to find the maximum value along each column and row respectively.

You can generate a simple matrix to compare the result with `imdilate`:

```
a=magic(8)
rtn = dilation(a)

b=imdilate(a,ones(3))
```

Besides `imdilate`, you can also use

```
c=ordfilt2(a,9,ones(3))
```

to get the same result ( implements a 3-by-3 maximum filter. )

**EDIT**

You may have a try on 3D image with `imdilate` as well:

```
a(:,:,1)=magic(8);
a(:,:,2)=magic(8);
a(:,:,3)=magic(8);
mask = true(3,3,3);
mask(2,2,2) = false;
d = imdilate(a,mask);
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for explaining. The size of the imdilate function returns in (x, y, 3) but the function in my questions is of size (x, y)... I'm assuming I would need to flatten the imdilate? Is that possible?

Comment: Finally rtn is 2D matrix. You can observe it from your workspace. The max functions on the 3rd dimension of rtn and returns you the 2D result. Note that rtn_two is also a 2D matrix

Comment: I must be sending it a 3D image. Is there a why to flatten the returned matrix if it is returned in 3D? (lose the 3 from the (x,y,3)) if that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: you can do the dilation at R,G,B channel respectively. Since you will find local maximum on each channel, then still return a 3D matrix. In fact imdilate also accepts 2D input only.

Comment: I updated my answer by providing you a possible code on 3D data with imdilate function. After all, rgb2gray on your original image is the easiest and most straightforward one

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the additional information. Thanks for posting.